# Pentaho 6 Quartz DB error after switching to postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, pentaho

I am moving our Pentaho 4 installation to new server and also updating it to pentaho 6 with postgresSQL databases instead of hypersql.

I have been following this guide: http://helicaltech.com/steps-migrate-oracle-pentaho/
even that it is meant for Oracle, files needed to be edited looks pretty much same.
There is one exception, as I have not changed file *biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/quartz/quartz.properties* because it already contains `org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate` which I believe is postgres configuration.

However, when I try to start my bi-server, I am getting into error that prevents my bi-server to start. Here is the *catalina.out* exception:

```
18-Oct-2016 15:56:57.618 INFO [Thread-17] org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.initDestination Setting the server's publish address to be /lineage
18-Oct-2016 15:56:58.421 INFO [Thread-17] org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.initDestination Setting the server's publish address to be /marketplace
15:56:58,467 ERROR [0] [[org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationAdmin]]Cannot use configuration org.pentaho.requirejs for [org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService, id=495, bundle=187/mvn:pentaho/pentaho-requirejs-osgi-manager/6.0.1.0-386]: No visibility to configuration bound to mvn:pentaho/pentaho-server-bundle/6.0.1.0-386
********************************************************************************
15:57:14,694 ERROR [EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener] EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener.ERROR_0007_SQLERROR
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "RUNSCRIPT"
  Position: 1
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:405)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:333)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:228)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:228)
        at org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener.verifyQuartzIsConfigured(EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener.java:176)
        at org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener.startup(EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener.java:100)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$2.call(PentahoSystem.java:436)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$2.call(PentahoSystem.java:427)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.runAsSystem(PentahoSystem.java:406)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:427)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.access$000(PentahoSystem.java:82)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$1.call(PentahoSystem.java:358)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$1.call(PentahoSystem.java:355)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.runAsSystem(PentahoSystem.java:406)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:355)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:326)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:222)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.SolutionContextListener.contextInitialized(SolutionContextListener.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1101)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1786)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15:57:14,696 ERROR [Logger] Error: Pentaho
15:57:14,696 ERROR [Logger] misc-org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem: org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener
org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:363)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:326)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:222)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.SolutionContextListener.contextInitialized(SolutionContextListener.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1101)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1786)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$2.call(PentahoSystem.java:445)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$2.call(PentahoSystem.java:427)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.runAsSystem(PentahoSystem.java:406)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:427)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.access$000(PentahoSystem.java:82)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$1.call(PentahoSystem.java:358)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$1.call(PentahoSystem.java:355)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.runAsSystem(PentahoSystem.java:406)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:355)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$2.call(PentahoSystem.java:437)
        ... 24 more
15:57:14,696 ERROR [Logger] Error end:
Pentaho BI Platform server failed to properly initialize. The system will not be available for requests. (Pentaho Open Source BA Server 6.0.1.0-386) Fully Qualified Server Url = http://localhost:8080/pentaho/, Solution Path = /home/app_core/flexcore/pentaho/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions
18-Oct-2016 15:57:17.747 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /home/app_core/flexcore/pentaho/biserver-ce/tomcat/webapps/pentaho has finished in 43,862 ms
18-Oct-2016 15:57:17.747 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /home/app_core/flexcore/pentaho/biserver-ce/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
18-Oct-2016 15:57:17.882 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
18-Oct-2016 15:57:17.883 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /home/app_core/flexcore/pentaho/biserver-ce/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished in 136 ms
18-Oct-2016 15:57:17.885 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
18-Oct-2016 15:57:17.889 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
18-Oct-2016 15:57:17.890 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 45068 ms
```

I am not very certain with Java, so I would like to ask, if anybody can give me some hints where should I look for problem. Or what files should I check.

PS:

1. Yes, I have used *biserver-ce\data\postgres* files to create
   databases.
2. I have also checked pentaho oficial guide at link: *https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.0/0F0/0K0/040/0A0* but the Quartz settings looks same as mine.
3. I have tried different `validationQuery` settings, but that did not help.
4. I was also trying to find "Listener". And I have found it in
   *bi-server/pentaho-solutions/system/quartz/quartz.properties* but it is commented (dummy one = `#org.quartz.triggerListener.dummy.class = org.quartz.examples.DumbTriggerListener`) and no guide is doing anything with that
   setting.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this myself and found the answer here:
http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?153231-Pentaho-ce-5-Initialization-Exception

The solution is to create a table named QRTZ in the quartz DB:

```
CREATE TABLE "QRTZ"
(
  NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (NAME)
);
```

This worked for me and others in the thread in the link